# Trying to Run a Python script using EasyEclipse for Python, get error "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

This is my first time using Eclipse, so I think it must be some newbie configuration error. However, I can not sort it out, so I hope one of you might be able to help me.

This is what I did:

1. Installed Python 2.7
2. Installed EasyEclipse for Python 1.3.1
3. Went to Window>Preferences>Pydev>Interpreter-Python and selected C:\python27\python.exe
4. Created a new project (when I had to select project type, there was only python 2.3, 2.4, and 2.5, so I selected 2.5, even though I am running 2.7)
5. Created a file in that project with a simple helloworld.
6. Clicked the "Run" play button.

When I do this, I get the error "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

As I said, I get the feeling this is just some configuration issue. In particular, could it be something about my "run configuration"? I see this as a dialog box, but I really don't know what I am supposed to be doing in it.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The "Run" play button in Eclipse can definitely be finnicky. Have you tried running from the "Run" menu instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, exact same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. When I was creating a file, I needed to specify the .py extension. After doing this, the file ran.

Comment: where did specify .py?